# Как при большом количество запросов вернуть из БД каждый объект только 1 раз?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

Сабж. Есть метод в WebApi

```cs
public string Get() 
    {
          using(ApplicationContext db = new ApplicationContext()) 
       {
            var Domain = db.Domain.Where(x => x.TryChek == null).Where(b => b.InProgress == null).FirstOrDefault();
            Domain.InProgress = true;
            db.SaveChanges();
            Console.WriteLine("Выдали " + Domain.Name);
            return JsonSerializer.Serialize(Domain);
       }
    }
```

По задумке метод должен выбирать из бд первый объект подходящий по фильтрам, ставить этому объекту `temp.InProgress = true` сохранять и возвращать его. И больше этот объект по идеи не должен попасть в выборку. 
Но в консоле я вижу как один объект выдается по несколько раз, от 2 до 8.
Я предполагаю что объект не успевает сохранится и его берет другой поток. Пробовал оборачивать в`lock`, не помогает.  Как исправить?

Comment: `Пробовал оборачивать вlock, не помогает` покажите, как вы это делали? Но вообще да, если вам надо, чтобы 1 элемент обрабатывался только 1 раз, то надо как то синхронизировать потоки.

Comment: Оборачивал весь using в lock

Comment: покажите код, так непонятно что вы делали

Comment: Спасибо вы помогли) Нужно было сделать object locker статичным.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Самый простой и при этом самый медленный вариант, который не учитывает если вы запустите 2 или более серверов (процессов) одновременно.

Вы можете захватывать монитор на статический объект, то есть на объект, который существует в едиснтвенном экземрляре и расшарен между потоками.

Пример (пишу из головы, компилируемость не гаранттирую):

```
private static object _locker = new Object();

public string Get() 
{
    lock(_locker)
    {
        // тут ваш код. 
    }
}
```

Comment: А какой способ будет быстрее?

Comment: Есть разные варианты. Например, сделать это в виде транзакции в БД и пусть БД разбирается с конфликтами транзакций. Или попробовать для этого [использовать ORM](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/ef/core/saving/concurrency?tabs=data-annotations), или заранее выгрузить все доступные домены в память в массив и использовать атомарный Interlocked для инкремента индекса в массиве доступных доменов (тут вообще не понадобится синхронизация), ну или ещё 100500 вариантов.